# SMOTE for multi-class balance changes the shape of my dataset

Tags: python, neural-network, multiclass-classification, jupyter, smote

So I have a dataset of shape (430,17), that consists of 13 classes (**imbalanced**) and 17 features.
The end goal is to create a NN which btw works when I import the imblanced dataset, however when i try to over-sample the minority classes using **SMOTE in jupyter notebook**, the classes do get balanced but also the shape changes.

```
from imblearn.over_sampling import SMOTE
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
from imblearn.pipeline import Pipelineenter 

steps = [('onehot', OneHotEncoder()), ('smt', SMOTE())]
pipeline = Pipeline(steps=steps)

X_res, y_res = pipeline.fit_resample(X, y)
```

The y_res shape is (754,) from  y shape which was (430,), so upsampling works, also by checking:

```
unique, counts = np.unique(y_res, return_counts=True)
print(np.asarray((unique, counts)).T)
```

the classes have been balanced.
However, the X_res shape has now changed to (754, 5553), from X shape which was (430, 17).
Then, if I fit these data in my NN it doesnt work of course since the input_dim has changed for my input layer.

My **question** is, did the SMOTE procedure add not only rows to balance the classes but also columns?
**Should't I got X_res with shape (754, 17)?** and because I need these data for a NN they have to be arrays, or numpys, instead of pd.dataframes, which is also complicated to understand where that 5553 columns come from.

I am new in python and jupyter so I do not know how to solve this, and I would really appreciate any help :)

Comment: Why change the class distribution at all? [Statistics does not see class imbalance as so problematic](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/357466/are-unbalanced-datasets-problematic-and-how-does-oversampling-purport-to-he).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your understanding is correct: data balancing techniques like SMOTE will only add/remove rows (data points) not columns (features). I suspect your extra dimensions are due to one-hot-encoding.

Comment: Alright, thank you for the reply, but then how can I do a mutliclass balance with SMOTE? without using `steps = [('onehot', OneHotEncoder()), ('smt', SMOTE())]
pipeline = Pipeline(steps=steps)`

Comment: In SMOTE's `fit_resample(X, y)`, you could keep the one-hot-encoding of the `X` values if you'd like but its not needed.. The `y` values can be scalar values (binary, or multi classed as is) or `LabelEncoded` vectors which is what I think you were going after.